# How can I get the ServiceName in a Windows Service written in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

How can I get the service name programatically using `this.ServiceName` in a Windows Service written in C#? When I try this, it's asking for assembly reference but its not accepting anything:

```
string path = this.ServiceName + ".config";
```

but its getting error.

Comment: Can you tell us what the exact error you're getting is? If the compiler gives you an error, it's helpful to post it just as it appears. That gives us a lot more information than just "its getting error".

Comment: What does your code have to do with the question? And what error are you getting?

Comment: @leppie: Obviously the code is how he's trying to get the name of the service. That part is explained clearly enough. The problem is that he doesn't tell us what the error is.

Comment: sorry my error is---'Service.monServ' does not contain a definition for 'ServiceName' and no extension method 'ServiceName' accepting a first argument of type 'Service.monServ' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Does your class inherits "ServiceBase" ?

Comment: @Saeed: `typeof(this)` is nonsensical.

Comment: @HABJAN in main function its like this  ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
            ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
   {                
    new Service1() 
   };
            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your service needs to inherit `ServiceBase` from `System.ServiceProcess.dll`.

When you will have that you will be able to access `this.ServiceName` property.

Sample:

```
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{
    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        string test = this.ServiceName;
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
    }
}
```

If you want to access it from Main() (Program class), then you can do something like this:

```
namespace WindowsService1
{
    static class Program
    {
        static ServiceBase[] _servicesToRun;

        static void Main()
        {
            _servicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
            { 
                new Service1() 
            };

            string serviceName = _servicesToRun[0].ServiceName;

            ServiceBase.Run(_servicesToRun);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited my answer based on your last input where you are trying to access service name from main function.

Answer (score 3):

To find the .config file for your service, do *not* use the service name.  That's not how the CLR works, it selects the .config file based on the EXE name.  Fix:

```
 var path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile;
```

Answer (score 0):

To access the configuration file you need the application name not the service name (if you are using standard .Net application configuration files).

To get the application executable use System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName